# Copy and paste MySQL query into command line does not work

Tags: mysql

The title says it all. I have absolutely no idea why copy and paste MySQL query into command line does not work. I tried very simple query like `select * from table` so I am certain it has something to do with MySQL (or the copy and paste step), not the syntax error. I wonder how I could fix this problem.

The error message I get is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...
```

Comment: Title says "does not work" which really does not help explain the problem. Please include **the exact error text** in your question.

Comment: provide what exactly did you copy? maybe there are some missing query resulting to errors?

Answer (score 0):

So i guess you already open MYSQL shell using cmd so you can type your query.

first of all you need to select a db from which you can select your tables.

```
SHOW DATABASES; -- this will show database list available in MYSQL
USE DB_NAME; -- it will select the database
SHOW TABLES; -- list of tables
SELECT * FROM table; -- here you can write your query
```

For reference see the following : https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line